# conda update removed conda

Tags: software-installation, updates, anaconda, conda

I have just updated conda, and I fell into an error from which I could not recover so far.
I am copying here the essential lines that illustrate the apparent problem (and below the full output).
The update removed `conda`, and then exited prior to finishing due to a version mismatch.
So now I don't have *any* version of `conda` (nor `conda-env`).

**How can I solve this, preferably without reinstalling everything?**

```
$ conda update --prefix /home/user1/anaconda3 anaconda
Fetching package metadata .........
...
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - conda-forge::brotlipy-0.7.0-py36he6145b8_1001.tar.bz2
  - conda-forge::brotlipy-0.7.0-py36h8f6f2f9_1001.tar.bz2
...
The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:                  4.2.13-py36_0            conda-forge --> 4.10.3-py36h5fab9bb_2   conda-forge
    conda-env:              2.6.0-0                  conda-forge --> 2.6.0-1                 conda-forge
...
Fetching packages ...
...
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
Installing conda-forge::conda-env-2.6.0-1 requires a minimum conda version of 4.3.                                                                                     |   9%
[~/anaconda3/bin]$ conda --version
bash: /home/user1/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
```

---

**Complete output**

```
$ conda update --prefix /home/user1/anaconda3 anaconda
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........conda update --prefix /home/user1/anaconda3 anaconda

Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - conda-forge::brotlipy-0.7.0-py36he6145b8_1001.tar.bz2
  - conda-forge::brotlipy-0.7.0-py36h8f6f2f9_1001.tar.bz2

Package plan for installation in environment /home/santiago/anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _libgcc_mutex-0.1          |      conda_forge           3 KB  conda-forge
    blas-1.0                   |              mkl           6 KB
    conda-env-2.6.0            |                1           2 KB  conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng-11.2.0        |      he4da1e4_14         4.2 MB  conda-forge
    libgomp-11.2.0             |      h1d223b6_14         429 KB  conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex-4.5          |            1_gnu          22 KB  conda-forge
    charset-normalizer-2.0.12  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          35 KB  conda-forge
    idna-3.3                   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          55 KB  conda-forge
    python_abi-3.6             |          2_cp36m           4 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2021.5.30          |   py36h5fab9bb_0         141 KB  conda-forge
    libgcc-ng-11.2.0           |      h1d223b6_14         906 KB  conda-forge
    pysocks-1.7.1              |   py36h5fab9bb_3          27 KB  conda-forge
    setuptools-58.0.4          |   py36h5fab9bb_2         966 KB  conda-forge
    tqdm-4.63.1                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          80 KB  conda-forge
    brotlipy-0.7.0             |py36he6145b8_1001         347 KB  conda-forge
    conda-package-handling-1.7.3|   py36h8f6f2f9_0         916 KB  conda-forge
    libgcc-7.2.0               |       h69d50b8_2         304 KB  conda-forge
    pycosat-0.6.3              |py36h8f6f2f9_1006         107 KB  conda-forge
    urllib3-1.26.9             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         100 KB  conda-forge
    requests-2.27.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          53 KB  conda-forge
    conda-4.10.3               |   py36h5fab9bb_2         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        11.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _libgcc_mutex:          0.1-conda_forge          conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex:          4.5-1_gnu                conda-forge
    blas:                   1.0-mkl                             
    brotlipy:               0.7.0-py36he6145b8_1001  conda-forge
    certifi:                2021.5.30-py36h5fab9bb_0 conda-forge
    charset-normalizer:     2.0.12-pyhd8ed1ab_0      conda-forge
    conda-package-handling: 1.7.3-py36h8f6f2f9_0     conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:              11.2.0-h1d223b6_14       conda-forge
    libgomp:                11.2.0-h1d223b6_14       conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng:           11.2.0-he4da1e4_14       conda-forge
    pysocks:                1.7.1-py36h5fab9bb_3     conda-forge
    python_abi:             3.6-2_cp36m              conda-forge
    tqdm:                   4.63.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0      conda-forge
    urllib3:                1.26.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0      conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:                  4.2.13-py36_0            conda-forge --> 4.10.3-py36h5fab9bb_2   conda-forge
    conda-env:              2.6.0-0                  conda-forge --> 2.6.0-1                 conda-forge
    idna:                   2.2-py36_0                           --> 3.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    libgcc:                 4.8.5-2                              --> 7.2.0-h69d50b8_2        conda-forge
    pycosat:                0.6.1-py36_1                         --> 0.6.3-py36h8f6f2f9_1006 conda-forge
    requests:               2.12.4-py36_0                        --> 2.27.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0     conda-forge
    setuptools:             27.2.0-py36_0                        --> 58.0.4-py36h5fab9bb_2   conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Fetching packages ...
_libgcc_mutex- 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.04 MB/s
blas-1.0-mkl.t 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   3.82 MB/s
conda-env-2.6. 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.25 MB/s
libstdcxx-ng-1 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00  10.47 MB/s
libgomp-11.2.0 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   5.21 MB/s
_openmp_mutex- 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   5.91 MB/s
charset-normal 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   6.50 MB/s
idna-3.3-pyhd8 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   6.79 MB/s
python_abi-3.6 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   2.75 MB/s
certifi-2021.5 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   3.25 MB/s
libgcc-ng-11.2 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   5.92 MB/s
pysocks-1.7.1- 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   6.94 MB/s
setuptools-58. 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.22 MB/s
tqdm-4.63.1-py 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   2.16 MB/s
brotlipy-0.7.0 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   3.80 MB/s
conda-package- 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.15 MB/s
libgcc-7.2.0-h 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   3.38 MB/s
pycosat-0.6.3- 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   2.52 MB/s
urllib3-1.26.9 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   3.71 MB/s
requests-2.27. 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   7.28 MB/s
conda-4.10.3-p 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01   1.99 MB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
Installing conda-forge::conda-env-2.6.0-1 requires a minimum conda version of 4.3.                                                                                     |   9%
[~/anaconda3/bin]$ conda --version
bash: /home/user1/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
```